# When I click on login button it is directly going into else part in cakephp

Tags: cakephp

if I click on login button, it is taking empty input values since the condition is directly going into else part of cakephp.

Below is the code:

```
 if($this->request->is('post'))
        {
            if(isset($this->data['Loginsubmit']))
            {

             if($this->data['Reg']['email']=='')
                {
                    echo 'hii'; 
                }
                elseif( $this->data['Reg']['password']=='')
                {
                      echo "hi";
                }
                else
                {
                   $result = $this->Reg->find('list',array('conditions'=>array('email'=>$this->request->data['Reg']['email'], 'password'=>$this->request->data['Reg']['password'],'status'=>1)));
                pr($result);
                 if(!empty($result)){
                    $email=$this->request->data['Reg']['email'];
                    $this->Session->write('Reg', $result);
                       $this->redirect(array('action' => 'login'));}               
         else{$this->Flash->error("invalid");
                }
                 $result = $this->Reg->find('all');
                $this->set('results',$result);
               }
```

Comment: print_r($this->data); to check which value get from submit form.

Comment: thank u i got the answer

Comment: no need to thanks welcome :)

Answer (score 0):

Hi please do like this:

```
public function beforeFilter() {
parent::beforeFilter();
// Allow users to register and logout.
$this->Auth->fields = array(
'email' => 'email',
'password' => 'secretword'
);
}

public function login() {
if(!$this->Auth->Reg('id')){        
$this->layout="login";          
if ($this->request->is('post')) {
App::uses('Validation', 'Utility');
$user=0;
if(Validation::email($this->request->data['email'])) 
$user = $this->Reg->find('first', array(
'conditions' => array(  'Reg.email' => $this->request->data['email'],
),'recursive' => -1      ));          

if($user)
{
$this->request->data['email']=$user['Reg']['email'];
}
$this->request->data=array('Reg'=>$this->request->data);

if ($this->Auth->login()) {         
return $this->redirect($this->Auth->redirectUrl());
}               

$this->Session->setFlash(__('Invalid username or password, try again'));            

}
}
else
{
return $this->redirect($this->Auth->redirectUrl());
}   

}
```

Please review & share your feedback.